# Programming Languages in Visual Studio 2012 Installer

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've read in the [Visual Studio blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/06/04/setup-improvements-for-visual-studio.aspx?PageIndex=3#comments) that at least, in the setup for VS 2012 RC there was no way to select which programming languages to install.

My question is:  Does the final version of VS 2012 Setup let me choose what languages to install?

I mean, if I don't want to install C++ or VB.Net, can I do that as I always did in previous versions?

I just don't want to waste space in my SSD (just 128 gb) with things that I don't use.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are only options to select some other features (Blend, LightSwitch, Silverlight etc) and VS interface languages.

Microsoft explains why here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/06/04/setup-improvements-for-visual-studio.aspx?PageIndex=5#comments

You can vote for this feature to be added to a future release here
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2930718-provide-installation-customization-options-to-excl