# Visual Studio 2012 Program Languages

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I installed visual studio 2012 Ultimate edition I didn't saw to ask me a question about what programming languages I prefer to install. It automatically installed all languages (C#,C++...). Is it normal or I missed the window which I choose which languages I want ?

Comment: I don't see what the issue is here.

Comment: Dupe Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329372/programming-languages-in-visual-studio-2012-installer?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

This is normal. Visual Studio 2012 by default installs all features.